# Convert pressure to energy

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, pressure, energy-conservation, piezoelectric

I read a little about electricity being created from pressure, [Piezoelectricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity). I'm still pretty newbie about it though.

Let's say I want to charge a battery from that technique, using my hands to press / tap on something. Besides me having all day to do that, what items/technology would be required in order to achieve that? Any specific links or guidance would be great.

Comment: Search Google for [piezoelectric charger](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=piezoelectric%20charger) or something similar.

Comment: Are you interested in the physics behind piezoelectricity and how to create a current from it or more interested in designing an actual device. For the engineering side electronics.stackexchange.com is much better suited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The piezo electric effect is caused by the distortion of, normally, a crystalline solid. By applying pressure, you are creating an electromechanical interaction between the crystals electric and mechanical states. It is also a reversible process, i.e. applying a current to an piezo electric material will distort it (this is how most buzzers work or the annoying chirp of a smoke detector).

To try this, you could grab a quartz crystal (or any other piezo you may have), attach electric leads to it and then connect the leads to a multimeter. Hit the crystal with a hammer and you will see a spike in voltage using the multimeter.

If you wired a piezo material into a basic circuit connecting it to a capacitor, you could generate a current to charge that capacitor (batteries are a little trickier).

The [hyperphysics page](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/solids/piezo.html) has some more information that might be helpful.

If you want to try it out yourself take a look at [this instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/PIEZO-GENERATOR/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is the current permanent under constant pressure or shall the pression vary ? I couldn't understand this from the Wikipedia formulas. In the first case one could build a battery with continuous voltage.